# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<..>' with ts mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

```
const mongooseResponse = await mongoose.connect(mongoUri);


const game = await GameSchema.create({
  image: "test",
  title: "StarBurst"
})

GameSchema.findOne({title: "starburst"})
console.log(game)
```

I have tried to create a mongoose schema to save some data. here I just create some test data.

but an error occurs when I use the `findOne` where i specify a title.

It gives me the following error:

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<{ type: String; unique: true; required: true; index: true; }> | undefined'.`

Here is how i created my Schema:

```
import { Document, model, Schema } from "mongoose";

export type GameModel =  Document  & {
    image: {type: String},
    title: {type: String, unique: true, required: true, index: true},
    rank:  {type: Number},
    providerAmount: {type: Number},
    nestedValues: [
        {RTP: {type: String}},
        {"Max Win": {type: String}},
        {"Min Bet": {type: String}},
        {Volatility: {type: String}},
        {Betways: {type: String}},
        {Release: {type: String}},
        {Devices: {type: String}}
    ]
}


const GameSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    image: {type: String},
    title: {type: String, unique: true, required: true, index: true},
    rank:  {type: Number},
    providerAmount: {type: Number},
    nestedValues: [
        {RTP: {type: String}},
        {"Max Win": {type: String}},
        {"Min Bet": {type: String}},
        {Volatility: {type: String}},
        {Betways: {type: String}},
        {Release: {type: String}},
        {Devices: {type: String}}
    ]
})

export default model<GameModel>('Game', GameSchema)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use the model, not the schema:

```
    const game = await GameModel.create({
  image: "test",
  title: "StarBurst"
})
    
   let result = await GameModel.findOne({title: "starburst"})
    console.log(game)
```